# How to extract this string with JQ

Tags: json, shell, jq

I have a JSON file like this :

```
{
  "filter": [
    {
      "id": "id_1",
      "criteria": {
        "from": "mail1@mail.com"
      },
      "action": {
        "addLabelIds": [
          "Label_1"
        ],
        "removeLabelIds": [
          "IMPORTANT",
          "SPAM"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "id_2",
      "criteria": {
        "from": "mail2@mail.com"
      },
      "action": {
        "addLabelIds": [
          "Label_2"
        ],
        "removeLabelIds": [
          "IMPORTANT",
          "SPAM"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to extract **id value** only where **from = mail2@mail.com**

I have tried this but does not work :

```
jq '.filter[] | select(.criteria.from | test("mail2@mail.com"; "i")) | .id'
```

Have you got any idea?

Thanks
L.

Comment: Can you write a title that describes the technical challenge you're encountering, so people with that same problem can find your question and its answers? Right now someone needs to read the body to know what "this" is.

Comment: Works OK for me. I get `"id_2"`

Comment: That said, a regex `test()` is overkill here if all you care about is equality; you can just `select(.criteria.from == "mail2@mail.com")`. And when you use a regex you need to worry about whether it's doing a substring match vs an exact/anchored match, etc.

Comment: See your code running at https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/OddballBeneficialAutoexec#main.sh with the expected/intended/desired output `"id_2"`

Comment: @ggorlen : what have you done?

Comment: here https://jqplay.org/ I get this error when I test the code : jq: error (at <stdin>:1387): null (null) cannot be matched, as it is not a string
exit status 5

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : you're right equality is enough and your code works fine. thanks again

Comment: jqplay binary seems to be old, from [3 years ago](https://github.com/owenthereal/jqplay/tree/master/bin/linux_amd64)

Comment: @LMC - jqplay is running the most recent "official" release (jq 1.6), which, as you observed, is quite old, though for present purposes, this makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @Charles Duffy
solution:

```
select(.criteria.from == "mail2@mail.com")
```